# change ScrollView scrollBarStyle programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-scrollview

I am trying to implement different styles for the ScrollView's scrollBarStyle in Android. I am well aware that the setScrollBarStyle() method is used, however I am not aware of what particular styles to access.

Could anyone please provide some additional information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this types

```
SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET
SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY
SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET
```

like `setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET);`

Comment: This is correct, except that these constants are defined in the View class. For example:
`View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY`